# Simplification of identity with square roots

Tags: quadratics, radicals, common-root

$\dfrac{\sqrt{x + 1}}{2x + 1} + \dfrac{\sqrt{2x + 1}}{x + 1} = 1 \tag 1$

How can I find the value of $x$ in this question?

Comment: Please show your attempts so far.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for editing

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please edit your post to include more information about the problem what help you would like. Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this algebraically, isolate one of the square roots on one side of the equation, square both sides, isolate the other square root, square again, simplify and take the numerator.  You'll get a polynomial of degree $8$ whose roots can't be expressed in radicals (its Galois group is $S_8$). One of the real roots of that polynomial is the solution.

In practice, numerical methods (e.g. Newton's) are the way to go.